# bash commandline jslint wont scan file and wont give an error

Tags: node.js, jslint

Why wont my jslint scan a file in bash?

On a fresh install of kubuntu

I installed node

```
sudo apt-get install node
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Then

```
sudo npm install jslint -g
```

All installs worked well with no errors

my issue comes when I type: I use tab to auto complete

```
a@a:~/Desktop$ jslint test.js 
a@a:~/Desktop$
```

it does nothing just creates a new line why? the file clearly has errors

PS proof it all installed

```
a@a:~/Desktop$ nodejs -v
v0.10.25
a@a:~/Desktop$ npm -v
1.3.10
```

Comment: the latest - version  - downloaded it yesterday

Comment: @Hello-World - What's in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had installed node and not nodejs as they are two different thing

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```